# create navigation bar for tableView programmatically in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

I want to create navigation bar for my table view controller class programmatically would you please help me?
I couldn't fix it!

Thanks in advance!
I'm really new to iOS programming!

here is the code for my table view controller class

```
 @implementation CheckedInOut

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
 return 0;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...

 return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib               name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont create a navigation bar for a table view controller, what you should do is create a navigation controller and set the table view controller as its root

```
UITableViewController *myTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *tableViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myTableViewController];

//use the navigation controller here instead of how you had used the table view controller
```

Comment: it is placed where you create the table view controller. e.g. if it is your root controller, in the app delegate you would set the tableViewNavigationController as the windows rootViewController instead of myTableViewController

Comment: 12 sorry I'm relly new to the iOS, but I put my code about that's my class for table view controller

Comment: you cant set the navigation bar for a viwe controller inside that view controller, it needs to be done before that view controller is displayed. somewhere in your code you must be creating an instance of CheckedInOut. you need to create a UINavigationController with CheckedInOut as the rootViewController and use the navigation controller instead

Comment: apples [view controller guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) is a good read to get an idea of why it needs to be set up that way

Answer (score 0):

these three lines

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];// or UITableVC as which VC you have in your file
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view]; // this is an important line if missed out dont show navController
```

should be added after

```
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

in **appDelegate.m**  **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method