# Changing title in UINavigationBar when a row from UITableView is touched

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Ok, so I have tried this a lot of different ways...

At the moment I have placed the `UINavigationBar` with the IB. Then declared it with `IBOutlet`.

From there I can't seem to change the title no matter what i try. Even just in `ViewDidLoad`.

Also, I dont need to assign the delegate of the navbar do i?

Here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController < UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *myArrayOne;
    NSArray *myArrayTwo;
    UITextView *myTextView;
    UINavigationBar *myNavBar;   
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myArrayOne;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myArrayTwo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *myNavBar;


@end
```

and:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

//Synthesising anything with a property call in the .h file.
@synthesize myArrayOne;
@synthesize myArrayTwo;
@synthesize myTextView;
@synthesize myNavBar;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //declaring and instantiating datapaths and also
    // reading into arrays from plist.
    NSString *datapath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myListOne" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSString *datapath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myListTwo" ofType:@"plist"];

    myArrayOne = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:datapath1];
    myArrayTwo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:datapath2];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Hi";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


#pragma mark - TableView Delegate stuff

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //myNavBar.title = [myArrayOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - TableView Datasource stuff

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //returns amount of items inside myArrayOne as amount of rows
    return [myArrayOne count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *myCell = nil;
    myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myReuseCell"];

    if (myCell == nil)
    {
        myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myReuseCell"];
    }

    myCell.textLabel.text = [myArrayOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return myCell;
}

@end
```

the actual code to change the title is just one way i have tried...

Any other way? And do I need to link the navigationbar in the IB with anything?

Comment: you can simply use self.title in navigation controller based projects.. not worked??

Comment: Well I couldnt get it to work... Could I implement that inside of a didSelectRowAtIndexPath for my UITableView?

Comment: Also.. I just made a single view application. And its set onto just a View controller not a navigation controller...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a navigation bar without a navigation controller, you have to give it a stack (in your case, a stack of one) navigation items.

In `viewDidLoad` of your view controller, add your view controller's navigation item to the stack:

```
self.myNavBar.items = @[self.navigationItem];
```

Now you can set the title like so:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Hello";
```

and it will appear in your navigation bar.

Comment: This is what i want to do! Thank you! However.. I couldn't get this to work either. I have copied your code and placed it underneath my code in ViewDidLoad but still the title remains unchanged. Is there anything I need to do in the interface? Like link something to somewhere and change a property? Also... I am not familiar with using the syntax 'self'. When is that applicable?

Comment: 1. [super viewDidLoad] should be the first thing you call in that method, not the last. 2. You must have created an outlet to the navigation bar - you have self.navBar in your code so I assume this is the case. 3. `self` means, well, self. It's a fundamental concept in objective-c, if you don't understand it you need to go back to some basic tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The solution above by jrturton works fine UNLESS you also have a UIBarButtonItem (e.g. a "Done" button) in the UINavigationBar.  In that case, the proposed solution causes the UIBarButtonItem to disappear.

Here's how to do it in a way that lets you change the UINavigationBar title but also preserve the UIBarButtonItem:

Add `IBOutlet UINavigationItem *myNavigationItem;` to your code.

In IB, in the outline view (not the storyboard view), right click the containing UIViewController and drag to the UINavigationItem that was automatically created by IB inside the UINavigationBar and connect to `myNavigationItem`.

Back in your code, add `self.myNavigationItem.title = @"Hello";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a navigationController instead why don't you check this link:

[create navigation bar for tableView programmatically in objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537069/create-navigation-bar-for-tableview-programmatically-in-objective-c)

and if you already have a navigation controller in your app delegate, then you should remove the IBoutlet you've created then use:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Hi";
```

for this will be referring the navigationController in your app delegate.

Comment: Surely I can create a UINavbar without doing it programmatically? Otherwise what is the point of being able to drop a navbar onto the storyboard?

Comment: I think you have missed to link delegate of the navigation bar in your nib file to the file owner

Comment: try adding UINavigationBarDelegate to your .h class next to UITableViewDelegate

Comment: ok and how about you try this: UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"A Title"];
theNavigationBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];
[item release];